# Linux Mint and XAMPP: not loading my.cnf file changes

Tags: linux-mint, mysql, xampp

I am trying to set innodb_log_file_size and max_allowed_packet values on my mysql. I am using xampp under Linux Mint 20.

So I edited

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

The file looks like:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram
[mysqld]
innodb_log_file_size=256M
max_allowed_packet=256M
```

I finally restarted mysql with:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

But I am not getting the new values if I execute

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

on my mysql.

What am I missing?

Comment: Either you haven't actually restarted it or it uses a different conf file or some other file redefines your options. `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart` doesn't look like it works with a system-wide installed MySQL/MariaDB service but I might be wrong.